# Installing Ad-Hoc Android App

Tags: android, xamarin, installation, apk

I am using Visual Studio and Xamarin to build an android app. The app runs on the tablet while debugging and in release mode, but when I archive the solution and install it on the tablet I get app not installed.

The app goes through the install process perfectly and i can open it instead of pressing done but as soon as i use the application icon I get a pop saying "App isn't installed". The current tablet I am using is the Pixel C running android 7.1 which i am targeting. The application also successfully installs and runs on other tablets i've tested.

The app is also signed following the tutorial provided by Xamarin. I have also tried uninstalling the app before installation and it still doesn't work.

If you need any further information let me know.

LogCat Error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=eu.netmr.input/md54912a688ba740e2300cbb893ea64d054.HomeScreen bnds=[307,194][631,424] (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{e6168a8 1741:com.google.android.apps.pixelclauncher/u0a24} (pid=1741, uid=10024) requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3101)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1518)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4228)
at com.android.launcher3.Launcher.startActivityForResult(SourceFile:1998)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4521)
at com.android.launcher3.Launcher.startActivitySafely(SourceFile:2849)
at com.android.launcher3.Launcher.startAppShortcutOrInfoActivity(SourceFile:2599)
at com.android.launcher3.Launcher.onClick(SourceFile:2420)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Comment: The Pixel C uses a Tegra X1 64-bit, assuming you are including at least armv7 (32-bit) support in your apk? Review the `logcat` output when you do an install, or just directly use `adb installl xxxxx.apk` and see what is going wrong with the apk

Comment: I am getting a Permission Denial starting intent error inside logcat

Comment: What is the full error?

Comment: I updated the question with the error.

Comment: You truncated where those errors are coming from but the `requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is fairly obvious.

Comment: But i have set that up in the manifest also it runs on other tablets

Comment: Missing my point, look at the process that is actually throwing the `Permission Denial`

Comment: I understand that it is throwing that error i just don't understand why it would on the pixel but not on the other tablets